# how to draw an optional decision tree with frame in netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I want to draw a tree like this:

[image]

In every node i just want to write a string.
How can i draw it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: there isn't any solution? :(

Answer (score 0):

These Link maybe useful for you,look at it:

1. [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)
2. [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html)